# Track the date in Zabbix

Tags: certificate, zabbix

How can I track the date in Zabbix?
There is a need to track application certificates and personal user certificates.
Perhaps it is worth creating an Item and assigning a certain date to it, and then in the Trigger to track the occurrence of this date. But date() doesn't work exactly as I expected, and now() only works with Epoth.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `now()` to know the difference between the certificate expiration date (as a Unix timestamp) and the time the item was last checked. This item can have a daily interval.

See https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/appendix/functions/time

Update: sample script to get expiration date as Unix timestamp.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

url="$1" # example.com

# Retrieve the certificate and extract the expiration date
expiration_date=$(echo | openssl s_client -connect $url:443 -servername $url 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate | cut -d "=" -f 2)

# Convert the expiration date to Unix timestamp
expiration_timestamp=$(date -d "$expiration_date" +"%s")

# Print the results
echo "$expiration_timestamp"
```

Using `timestamp` as the Item unit in Zabbix, allows Zabbix to display the timestamp as human readable in Latest Data.

Comment: To use now(), you will have to convert all certificate issue dates to Epoch(Number of seconds since the Epoch (00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970)) format. This is inconvenient and difficult to track. Perhaps there are other ways?

Comment: Debatable. Epoch is the Unix way, looks good to Linux people. Using "timestamp" as unit in Zabbix, it does the conversion back by itself in Latest Data. Adding a script to the answer.